# format.js not working in rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two controller named `client/orders` and `notary/orders`. Have click_me link in "client/orders".When i click the link i should pass ajax request to `notary/orders/pending_orders` and `reload the notary/orders/pending_orders` page.

This is my Ajax Call in client/orders/new

```
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
alert(9);
jQuery(".test_link").live("click", function(){
  alert("am clicked");
      jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/notary/orders/pending_orders",
      dataType: 'script',
      type: "get",
      data: {data:'hi'},
      success:function(){
          alert("success");
      },
      error:function(){
          alert("failure");   
      }
    });
})
```

});

```
<%= link_to "click me", "javascript:void(0);" , :class => "test_link" %>
```

This is my code in `notary/orders/pending_orders`

```
if request.xhr?
   respond_to do |format|
   format.js { render :js=>'location.reload();',
   :location => "notary/orders/pending_orders"}
   end
    end
```

But its reloads `client/orders/new` not `notary/orders/pending_orders`.But i want to reload 
notary/orders/pending_orders.How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the link `<%= link_to "click me", "javascript:void(0);" , :class => "test_link" %>`
is in `client/orders/new` and you want to update the page `notary/orders/pending_orders` from `client/orders/new`.

Since you are making request from `client/orders/new` , all your response will get update in `client/orders/new` only.

It seems you are doing a action in `client/orders/new` from one browser and listening the page `notary/orders/pending_orders` in another browser to update a notification when some changes happened in back-end.

To update a page (eg: showing notification in `notary/orders/pending_orders`) automatically when a change happened in the back-end, what I use to do is, I will put a separate listener for that something like this,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        notificationListener();
      }); 

      function notificationListener(){
        jQuery.ajax({
           url: "/notary/orders/pending_orders",
           type: "get",
           data: {data:'yourdata'},
           success:function(){
             if(expected result){
                //code to update browser view
             }
             else{
                setTimeout(notificationListener(),10000)
             }
           },
           error:function(){
              //
           }
      });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Your answer gave me more idea.Thanks for reply